# How to get the dataValueField when I select one node

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using kendoTreeView. I want to get the unitId when one node is selected.

This is my code.

```
  $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: 'unitId'
   });
```

dataSource example:

```
{
    "rows": [{
        "_token": "8cfd3e2133d936a6a65c6f7cfb80268a",
        "objectVersionNumber": null,
        "unitId": 10002,
        "parentId": 10001,
        "unitCode": "100000",
        "name": "Hand",
        "description": null,
        "managerPosition": null,
        "companyId": null,
        "enabledFlag": null,
        "unitCategory": null,
        "unitType": null,
        "positionName": null,
        "parentName": null,
        "parentCode": null,
        "hasChildren": true
    }],
    "success": true,
    "total": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which method of treeview are you using to capture the click event? You can write a select event that kendoTreeView provides which will give you data of the node you clicked/selected. You can refer this: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/events/select

If this doesn't work for you, can you share your DOJO or jsFiddle and I could further help.